# Django Registrations using User model

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to replicate Groupon using Django. I'm basically trying to achieve the below
1. A Merchant can register with the site
2. Can start creating campaigns

For the merchant registration part , I'm importing the User model and including a random MerchantID generator using random.

```
class Merchants(models.Model):
    merchant = models.OneToOneField(User)
    MerchantID = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    Storename = models.CharField(max_length = 25)


    def save(self):
        self.MerchantID = MerchantIDgen()
        super(Merchants,self).save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.merchant.username
```

The merchant is able to successfully register with the site. However, I'm having trouble enabling the create campaigns part.

the html link to the create campaign part is:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<a href = '/Merchants/{{user.username}}/Campaign'> start a campaign </a><br/>
```

ideally , I would want the variable portion to pull in the MerchantID value from the user. But I cant seem to pull this value from the User model( which makes sense since its sitting in the Merchants table)

In order the accomplish the above, is it better for me to just scrap the User model and just do the registration from the Merchant Model alone? (am I right in assuming that by doing so , I wouldn't have access to user authentication etc?)

Or is there any other way to pull the MerchantID using the user model?

Answer (score 0):

figured a workaround which basically is to filter using username from user and using that instance to filter the Merchants table